# e.preventDefault will block anchor tag after clicking on li

Tags: html, jquery

hello friends my project header and footer part is different & i want to make page link active in header on click of each page link. Code is working, but, due to `e.preventDefault()`, the anchor tag is not working and if it is removed, the active class is added to `li`. What is solution to handle this situation?

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php"> <span>L</span>ifer</a></h1> -->
        <span><a href="home.php"><img src="images/sv_logo.webp" class="navbar-brand" alt="digital-marketing-logo" ><!-- The Inside Story 100*180--></a></span>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <nav class="link-effect-2" id="link-effect-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="home.php" class="effect-3">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php" class="effect-3">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.php" class="effect-3">Services</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="blog.php" class="effect-3">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="services.php" class="dropdown-toggle effect-3" data-toggle="dropdown">Services<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu agile_short_dropdown">
                        <li><a href="icons.php">Web Icons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="typography.php">Typography</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li> -->
                <li>
                    <a href="contactus.php" class="effect-3">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</nav>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("active"); 
            $(this).addClass("active"); 
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your ``ready`` function misses closing braces and parenthesis, does it not ?

Comment: In your CSS, set `pointer-events: none;` on the `li` and `pointer-events: all;` on the `a` tags

Comment: @Daniel_Knights any change in jquery because not working as per your changes. now link is works but it is not active

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my comment, you could target the anchor tags in your CSS like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <span><a href="home.php"><img src="images/sv_logo.webp" class="navbar-brand" alt="digital-marketing-logo" ><!-- The Inside Story 100*180--></a></span>
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <nav class="link-effect-2" id="link-effect-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="home.php" class="effect-3">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php" class="effect-3">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php" class="effect-3">Services</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="contactus.php" class="effect-3">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: hello your code works but anchar tag is not click due to e.defaultPrevent(). if it remove then active class is not apply

Comment: It navigates to a different page without `e.preventDefault()` so the change wouldn't persist

Comment: then what is solution

Comment: You could either store the value in `localStorage` and retrieve it on page change or listen for the `load` event, read the current path and apply the class based off that